# XML and iSeries RPGLE - development tools?

Tags: xml, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I've got a iSeries to .Net compact framework project.  It includes rgple programs exposed as web services and a Windows mobile app that uses the webservices.  Each iSeries program has a specific webservice wrapper and the .net app reference each.  I would like to come up with a more generic messaging service using XML.

I am fairly familiar with procesing XML in .Net.  But have no experience with XML on the iSeries.  What iSeries XML tools would you recommend?  And how best to get started/learn XML processing on the iSeries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM provides the [XML Toolkit for IBM System i5](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzamj/rzamjmain.htm).

You can also run Java which has an [XML parser](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzahh/rzahhxmlparserxslprocessor.htm).

RPG also has some [support for XML](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/books_web/c0925076167.htm) built into the langage.

You can get started by reading the IBM documentation at those links.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [RPG-XML Suite](http://www.rpg-xml.com). They wrote a wrapper to make it easier. I have not used it however.

Answer (score 0):

I have Used RPG-XML Suite by Krengletech and it works wonderfully.  The procedures provided are all within a binding directory so it's really easy to add them to your programs.  There are also several examples that you can cut and paste from that explain everything in detail.  AAron also provides a couple of commands that make it easy to create from scratch a program that either parses an incoming xml file or builds a template for creating your own webservice program.  I'm also extremely pleased with the support I've received from them.  I was up and running in a few days with my first webservice program.